# Another Button at UITableView Editing Mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I need an additional button next to the Delete button when in editing mode of UITableView Cells. Any suggestions for the purpose is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2104403/550177

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you first subclass UITableViewCell. In the respective init method you create the button and add it to the contentView as a subview. Make the button hidden. After that you overwrite layoutSubviews and position the button on your content view by setting the frame property of the button. Then also subclass willTransitionToState: and check if the state is UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask. If that's the case make the button visible. If not hide it.

Note: If you add an additional button to the UITableViewCell you also need to adjust the textLabel frame and other stuff to not overlap the button's rectangle.

Comment: Thank you for the response, however It'll be nice to have a sample source code to accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

or some other value than "check"

or

```
cell.editingAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
```

or with some other value than the info button, with it's target set to something appropriate

an accessory view trumps a type