# Changing the location of the minus sign in UITableView in Edit mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to change the location of the minus image from the left side of the cell to the middle of it. Tried reading here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html but couldn't find an easy way for doing that.

Thanks

Comment: Simple way to achieve ur requirement is using custom cell.

Comment: I have a custom cell and with willTransitionToState and didTransitionToState I managed to change the location of the minus BUT it only moves the minus image to the middle. The actuel button stays on the left side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom cell layoutSubviews method use:

```
if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellEditControl"]) {
        CGRect newFrame = subview.frame;
        //Use your desired x value
        newFrame.origin.x = 280;
        subview.frame = newFrame;    
}
```

as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8512461/1747635.