# How to change the position of minus button of tableview on editing mode(Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have found answer to this question in below link.But is in objective C.Please help to get it's Swift representation.

[Changing the location of the minus sign in UITableView in Edit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246738/changing-the-location-of-the-minus-sign-in-uitableview-in-edit-mode)

Answer (score 0):

Working example in Swift 3.0

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    for subview in self.subviews {
        if subview.isMember(of: NSClassFromString("UITableViewCellEditControl")!) {
            var newFrame: CGRect = subview.frame
            newFrame.origin.x = 280
            subview.frame = newFrame
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzRa6.png)