# UITableView custom swipe buttons with TwitterKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, twitter

I would like to implement custom swipe left/swipe right buttons on my `UITableView` which includes multiple `TWTRTweetTableViewCells` from `TwitterKit` as well as my own subclassed `UITableViewCell`. I want to customize beyond the basic `backgroundColor` and other items Apple makes it easy to change. This includes button height and position. To do this on my own subclassed `UITableViewCell` I just override `layoutSubviews`, find the button, and make changes to height (for example) as suggested here: [Set height of delete button that appears on swipe in UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502445/set-height-of-delete-button-that-appears-on-swipe-in-uitableviewcell). That works great. I can’t do this on my `TWTRTweetTableViewCells`, however, since I can't override `layoutSubviews` without the .m file. Is there some other way I can accomplish this?

The below screenshot illustrates the issue I’m trying to address. On swipe left, the “Info” and “Mute” buttons fill the entire height of the Tweet cell and look terrible. I want to limit the height and center the button on the cell, which, again, I’ve already accomplished on my own custom cells. How can I do this with a `TWTRTweetTableViewCell`?

[image]