# iOS 10: UITableViewCell's delete button custom height

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios10

Using custom UITableViewCell, I'm trying to change the height of tableViewCell's delete button. I've tried all the solutions available here on SO.

Everyone has mentioned that in customTableViewCell class we need to override `layoutSubviews` method and iterate over `self.subViews` to find a subView which should be equal to **UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView** or in other iOS versions it is **UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl** so I have used following code:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.0f];

    for (UIView *subView in self.subviews) {
        NSLog(@"subview: %@", self.subviews);
        if([NSStringFromClass([subView class]) rangeOfString:@"Delete"].location != NSNotFound) {
            CGRect newFrame = subView.frame;
            newFrame.size.height = 87;
            subView.frame = newFrame;
        }
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

But `self.subView` only have two views i.e.

- UITableViewCellContentView
- UITableViewCellSeparatorView

How to get tableViewCell's delete button view in iOS 10+?

### Edit

Here is my view hierarchy :

[image]

Comment: try accessing the subviews of `UITableViewCellContentView`. Although I would highly recommend against changing the height of the delete button

Comment: @Malik already tried this, `UITableViewCellContentView` only contains one subview which is UIView.

Comment: could be the subviews of that uiview. The quickest way to get the hierarchy is by using `Debug->View Debugging->Capture View Hierarchy` while debugging. There you can see the complete hierarchy and get a better idea of how to navigate to the button

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Was the delete button visible when you captured the hierarchy? You need to open the app, swipe to show the delete button and then capture hierarchy. If you can't find the delete button in the list, find it in the graphical view by rotating the captured view around. Once found, click on the delete button and it will automatically highlight it in the left panel

Comment: @Malik thanks a lot, I've found the complete view hierarchy when the delete button is visible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anybody who is struggling with the same problem.

In **iOS10+** view hierarchy for UITableView's delete button has been changed. Now it comes under UITableView - UISwipeActionPullView - **UISwipeActionStandardButton**

[image]

So now instead of overriding custom UITableViewCell's `layoutSubviews` method, we need to iterate UITableView subviews in order to get UISwipeActionStandardButton. And I found tableView's `willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath` delegate as an appropriate place,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    for (UIView *subview in tableView.subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UISwipeActionPullView"]) {
            if ([NSStringFromClass([subview.subviews[0] class]) isEqualToString:@"UISwipeActionStandardButton"]) {
                CGRect newFrame = subview.subviews[0].frame;
                newFrame.size.height = 72;
                subview.subviews[0].frame = newFrame;

                //Other changes on this view can also be applied like
                subview.subviews[0].backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                subview.subviews[0].layer.cornerRadius = 12;
                subview.subviews[0].layer.masksToBounds = YES;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is by far one of the most clearest answers i have seen on this topic . However if anyone is facing the same issue in IOS 13 , i have written a fix below

Answer (score 2):

Same code but works with `Swift 5` and `iOS 12+`

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        for subview in tableView.subviews {
            if NSStringFromClass(type(of: subview)) == "UISwipeActionPullView",
                let button = subview.subviews.first,
                NSStringFromClass(type(of: button)) == "UISwipeActionStandardButton" {

                button.backgroundColor = .red
                button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
                button.layer.masksToBounds = true
                (button as? UIButton)?.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
                (button as? UIButton)?.contentVerticalAlignment = .center
                (button as? UIButton)?.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
                button.superview?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.97, alpha: 1)
                button.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For IOS 13 , the Position has been yet again change , not inside table view it is once again in _UITableViewCellSwipeContainerView . Thus you should iterate through that as well.Take a look below

```
   ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) 
    isEqualToString:@"_UITableViewCellSwipeContainerView"]){

            for (UIView *deleteButtonSubview in subview.subviews){

                if ([NSStringFromClass([deleteButtonSubview class])
                     isEqualToString:@"UISwipeActionPullView"]) {



                    if ([NSStringFromClass([deleteButtonSubview.subviews[0] class]) isEqualToString:@"UISwipeActionStandardButton"]) {

                       //do what you want
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5, this works for iOS12, iOS13 and iOS14**

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // for iOS13, iOS14
    if let swipeContainerView = tableView.subviews.first(where: { String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "_UITableViewCellSwipeContainerView" }) {
      if let swipeActionPullView = swipeContainerView.subviews.first, String(describing: type(of: swipeActionPullView)) == "UISwipeActionPullView" {
        swipeActionPullView.frame.size.height -= 10
      }
    }

    // for iOS12
    tableView.subviews.forEach { subview in
      if String(describing: type(of: subview)) == "UISwipeActionPullView" {
        subview.frame.size.height -= 10
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.subviews.forEach { subview in
        if String(describing: type(of: subview)) == "_UITableViewCellSwipeContainerView" {
            if let swipeActionPullView = subview.subviews.first, String(describing: type(of: swipeActionPullView)) == "UISwipeActionPullView" {
                swipeActionPullView.frame.size.height -= 16
            }
        }
    }
}
```