# Not able find UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView in ios 11 layoutsubview subview in UITableviewcell?

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.ios, ios11

I have to override the height swipe delete button in Tableviewcell i used the below code it's work fine ios 10 but in ios11 i can't able find the UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView in layoutsubview class

```
 foreach (var views in this.Subviews)
    {
        if (views.Class.Name.ToString() == new NSString("UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView"))
        {
            CGRect newFrame = views.Frame;
            CGRect newframe1 = new CGRect(newFrame.X, 6, newFrame.Size.Width, 59);
            views.Frame = newframe1;

            foreach (var getButtonviews in views.Subviews)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("x:"+getButtonviews.Frame.X);
                Console.WriteLine("W:"+getButtonviews.Frame.Width);
                if (getButtonviews.Class.Name.ToString() == "_UITableViewCellActionButton")
                {
                    UIImage image = UIImage.FromBundle("img_line");
                    UIButton button = (UIButton)getButtonviews;
                    UIImageView imageview = new UIImageView();
                    imageview.Frame = new CGRect(getButtonviews.Frame.X + 120, 0, 1, getButtonviews.Frame.Height);
                    imageview.Image = image;
                    button.AddSubview(imageview);

                    foreach (var getButton in getButtonviews.Subviews)
                    {
                        if (getButton.Class.Name.ToString() == "UIButtonLabel")
                        {
                            UILabel label = (UILabel)getButton;
                            label.Font = UIFont.FromName("ProximaNova-Regular", 13);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: use the below link you can get the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46338159/ios-10-uitableviewcells-delete-button-custom-height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view hierarchy inside tableview has been changed after iOS10.

### `iOS8 - iOS10`

> UITableView -> UITableViewCell -> UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView -> _UITableViewCellActionButton

### `iOS11`

1. work with Xcode8

   > UITableView -> UITableViewWrapperView -> UISwipeActionPullView -> UISwipeActionStandardButton
2. work with Xcode9

   > UITableView -> UISwipeActionPullView -> UISwipeActionStandardButton

### Solution:

I make the code work both at **iOS8 - iOS11**, and I put all the code at `ViewWillLayoutSubviews` in ViewController , but first , we need to know which cell we are selecting.

```
public class TableDelegate : UITableViewDelegate
{
    YourViewController owner;

    public TableDelegate(YourViewController vc){
        owner = vc;
    }

    public override UITableViewRowAction[] EditActionsForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewRowAction hiButton = UITableViewRowAction.Create(
            UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default,
            "Hi",
            delegate {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            });
        return new UITableViewRowAction[] { hiButton };
    }

    public override void WillBeginEditing(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        owner.selectIndexPath = indexPath;
        owner.View.SetNeedsLayout();
    }

    public override void DidEndEditing(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        owner.selectIndexPath = null;
    }
}

public class TableSource : UITableViewSource
{

    string[] TableItems;
    string CellIdentifier = "TableCell";

    public TableSource(string[] items)
    {
        TableItems = items;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return TableItems.Length;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier);
        string item = TableItems[indexPath.Row];

        //---- if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        if (cell == null)
        { cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIdentifier); }

        cell.TextLabel.Text = item;

        return cell;
    }
}

public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    protected ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
    }

    public NSIndexPath selectIndexPath { get; set; }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        string[] tableItems = new string[] { "Vegetables", "Fruits", "Flower Buds", "Legumes", "Bulbs", "Tubers" };
        tableview.Source = new TableSource(tableItems);
        tableview.Delegate = new TableDelegate(this);
    }

    public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();

        if (this.selectIndexPath != null)
        {
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
            {
                // Code that uses features from iOS 11.0 and later
                foreach (UIView subview in tableview.Subviews)
                {
                    if (subview.Class.Name.ToString() == "UISwipeActionPullView")
                    {
                        foreach (var buttonViews in subview.Subviews)
                        {
                            if (buttonViews.Class.Name.ToString() == "UISwipeActionStandardButton")
                            {
                                //operate what you want.
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Code to support earlier iOS versions
                UITableViewCell cell = tableview.CellAt(this.selectIndexPath);
                foreach (UIView subview in cell.Subviews)
                {
                    if (subview.Class.Name.ToString() == "UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView")
                    {
                        foreach (var buttonViews in subview.Subviews)
                        {
                            if (buttonViews.Class.Name.ToString() == "_UITableViewCellActionButton")
                            {
                                //operate what you want.
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i get the  UISwipeActionPullView -> UISwipeActionStandardButton from uitableview can you give me any sample code.it will help me lot

Comment: @Kamalkumar.E I have attached the  whole code,please check it . If you still have any question, feel free to let me know.

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT, In my case cell is not even visible if I do build with iOS 11 and xcode9. Any idea ? I suspect something around wrapper view only but not able to catch it. See if you can help. Thanks

Comment: @torap Are you developing with ios or xamarin.ios? and can you open a new thread to describe your issue?

Comment: The optimal usage of owner in child(TableDelegate) has to be with WeakReference in order not to cause strong reference. Like this; `WeakReference<UIViewController> owner;`