# Change swipe to delete button height in UITableview in Xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have a table view with cells having some padding around them. I implemented swipe to delete feature and by default the delete button occupies the cell height.

I used below code for IOS 10 to align it with the visible cell height and it is screwing up the button height in a wierd way. Note : I have got it working fine in IOS 11 using a different set of code as the way to handle this is different between IOS 10 and IOS 11.

But below code for IOS 10 screws up button height. Looks like the layout subview gets called multiple times when user swipes and that is causing the button height to vary a lot. Any ideas of how to solve this.

```
public override void LayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.LayoutSubviews();
                if (Convert.ToInt16(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion.Split('.')[0]) < 11)
                {
                    foreach (var view in this.Subviews)
                    {
                        if (view.Class.Name.ToString() == "UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView")
                        {
                            CGRect newFrame = view.Frame;
                            newFrame.Y = newFrame.Y + 6;
                            newFrame.Height = newFrame.Height - 12;
                            view.Frame = newFrame;
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46721607/8187800).

The view hierarchy before iOS11 demonstrates as below

> UITableView -> UITableViewCell -> UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView -> _UITableViewCellActionButton

I see you get the `UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView`  not the Button .

Modify your code :

```
foreach (UIView subview in this.Subviews)
{
    if (subview.Class.Name.ToString() == "UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView")
    {
        foreach (var view in subview.Subviews)
        {
            if (view.Class.Name.ToString() == "_UITableViewCellActionButton")
            {
                CGRect newFrame = view.Frame;
                newFrame.Y = newFrame.Y + 6;
                newFrame.Height = newFrame.Height - 12;
                view.Frame = newFrame;
            }
        }
    }
}
```