# Prevent UITableViewCell subclass from allowing swipe to delete?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I’d like to prevent a custom `UITableViewCell` from swiping to show the red Delete button. I can disable this on the `UITableView`, but I’ve not seen any existing questions that allow this to be done within the cell class, meaning I don’t need to do it on every table that uses that cell.

Can I disable this (without disabling editing entirely, I have a custom pann-able overflow) directly inside the cell class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath and perform your test there.

If there is only one cell that will have this pannable overflow and you know which row, you could define a constant and test for that, like so:

```
#define kPANNABLE_OVERFLOW_CELL_ROW  7

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ( indexPath.row == kPANNABLE_OVERFLOW_CELL_ROW )
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

If you will have multiple, arbitrary cells that need this treatment, you'll need to handle it a bit differently.

Inside

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // create your table view cell
    if ( _Your_table_view_cell_is_the_pannable_overflow_type_ ) {
        cell.editingStyle = UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return indexPath.row != THE_ROW_YOU_WANT_TO_STOP;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to override `- (void)setEditing: animated:` method in the following way:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:NO animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

Try above code it just disable the delete button from tableview cell swipe.

**Edit:** hiding button from cell go here

[iPhone UITableView - Delete Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104403/iphone-uitableview-delete-button)